# Update UItableView in viewWillAppear?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, viewwillappear

I have problem with my `UItableview` that when I use `viewWillAppear` for retrieving updated data each time table is viewed this gives me exception .

Please can any one help me on how to refresh tableview in `viewWillAppear` so that it will be updated before `CellforrowAtindexPath` is called ?

Here is my code for `viewWillAppear`:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

     [super viewWillAppear:YES];
     [self.tableView reloadData];//table was filled in viewDidLoad.

}
```

Here is CellforrowAtindexPath` : (The exception is on mainArray which means that there is conflict in updating table through viewWillAppear and calling cell ):

```
//Methods to retrive all selected words , thier sound and picture for the mother
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifer = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell= [ tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer];

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifer];
    }
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
    UILabel *label ;

    label=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    NSString *value = [[self.mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label.text = value;
    label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
    label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

    //self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];TRY TO SEPARETE BETEWEEN LINES OF TABLE
    UIButton *butt =(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    NSString *value2 = [[self.mainArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    butt.restorationIdentifier= value2;
    [butt addTarget:self action:@selector(play:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    NSString *value3 = [[self.mainArray3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:value3];
    label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: putting code above `[super viewWillAppear:YES];` is a bad practice. By the way, `CellforrowAtindexPath` always calls after `reloaddata`. What exception you are getting?

Comment: is `self.mainArray` populated before the `[self.tableView reloadData]` is called ?

Comment: @VaibhavSaran yes i know it is bad but i read once that it will be called before CellforrowAtindexPath ? I got exception that the array is beyond index

Comment: @AhmedZ.Yes it does . However i got exception is that the array beyond index

Comment: there must be somthing missing with your `self.mainArray`. check wny it is out of index. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is calling then there is no need to call `reloaddata` !!

Comment: @VaibhavSaran I did put  [super viewWillAppear:YES]; after before my code and i have the problem still ?

Comment: could you tell me how you are launching this `viewcontroller`? using `push` or `pop`?

Comment: @VaibhavSaran what do you mean by cellForRowAtIndexPath is calling ? what i need is that updating my table view each time it is viewed ?

Comment: how are you filling `self.mainArray`

Comment: @VaibhavSaran I am using push with it

Comment: @VaibhavSaran for the first time it will be filled in ViewDidLoad

Comment: if you are showing this `viewcontroller` with push only, then there is no need to put `reloaddata` line into `viewWillAppear` also are you able to `NSLog` data inside `self.mainArray` in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @VaibhavSaran Yes i can . Do you know how to update my table without using reloaddata i need my cells to be updated each time the table appear ? Thank you for your response i rally appreciate it

Comment: could you send log of `self.mainArray`??

Comment: @VaibhavSaran                                                                   d = [[DB alloc] init];
    [d openConnection];
    
  NSMutableArray *catarr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    catarr = [d Category];
    NSInteger length ;
    length = [catarr count];
    self.mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for ( int i=0 ; i < length ; i++)
    {
        NSString *str = [catarr objectAtIndex:i];
        //Array for words
        NSMutableArray *wordarr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
        wordarr = [d CatRowName:str num:1];
        [self.mainArray addObject: wordarr];

Comment: it is weird, please send what `NSLog` shows your array. `NSLog(@"%@", self.mainArray)`

Comment: ok the exception said that my array is index 21 beyond bounds [0 .. 18]' @VaibhavSaran

Comment: what are these 3 arrays? `self.mainArray1`, `self.mainArray2`, `self.mainArray3`

Comment: one for retrieving all words one for their picture and one for their sounds @VaibhavSaran

Comment: ok, so in your code you are making different sections and rows both?

Comment: you should put all your contents on one `NSDictionary` then you need to put that `NSDictionary` inside every index of one `NSMutbleArray`

Comment: @VaibhavSaran Yes i have both

Comment: @VaibhavSaran do you think this is the reason of my problem

Comment: index out of range happen where there is one array whose range exceeded or multiple array index mismatch.
NSLog all your arrays after filling them and you will get the answer.

Comment: Please put clarifications into the question (as edits).  The comments aren't a great place for that because it's hard for users (coming here from google) to parse what's going on.  These comments will be purged, so if you want to keep something stick it in the question or an answer (if relevant).

Answer (score 0):

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;{

return self.mainArray.count;
}

if count is 0, table view won't call the other functions.